# No Output? PHP foreach doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

I am trying to form an acronym from a given text. The Idea here is that the first Letter in $text ($text[0]) will be taken and placed inside the array $storage using array_push(). Now, if there is a space inside the array, the letter of the next index should be a part of the Acronym. I am currently not getting an ouput, what am I missing?

```
public function Acronym($text)
        {
            $text = str_split($text);
            $count = strlen($text);
            $storage = array();

            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
            {
                array_push($storage, $text[0]);

                if($text[$i]==' ')
                {
                    array_push($storage, $text[$i+1]);
                }

                foreach($storage as $clean)
                {
                    echo $clean;
                }       
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Please provide example in- and output

Comment: Your algorithm implementation and explanation are two completely different things.

Comment: How you called this function and what output you received?

Comment: Why do you use `array_push()`? array_push — Push one or more elements onto the end of array. array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as: `$array[] = $var;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm suffers from a few fatal flaws:

1. You're calling `strlen()` on an array, when you should be calling `count()`:

   ```
   $text = str_split($text);
   $count = count($text);
   ```
2. However, you can index strings as arrays, so you don't need `str_split()` in this scenario, and you can keep `$count = strlen( $text);` by removing the call to `str_split()`.
3. This should only happen once, so it should be outside the loop (This implies starting `$i` at 1):

   ```
   array_push($storage, $text[0]);
   ```
4. Your `foreach` loop that prints the `$storage` array should be outside of the loop that is creating the acronym.
5. You can save the overhead of calling a function by using the shorthand `array_push()` notation. You should use `array_push()` when adding more than one element to an array. Otherwise, this will suffice:

   ```
   $storage[] = $text[0];
   ```
6. You need to `return` something from your function, otherwise you won't be able to access anything outside of it.

Put that all together, and you get this:

```
public function Acronym($text)
{
    $count = strlen( $text);

    $storage[] = $text[0];

    for( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if( $text[$i] == ' ') 
        {
            $storage[] = $text[$i+1]);
            $i++; // Can increment $i here because we know the next character isn't a space
        }
    }
    foreach($storage as $clean)
    {
        echo $clean;
    }
    return $storage;
}
```

That being said, there are far better implementations for forming an acronym giving a string input. Here is one that I can think of:

```
public function Acronym( $text) 
{
    $acronym = array();
    foreach( explode( ' ', $text) as $word)
    {
        $word = trim( $word);
        $acronym[] = strtoupper( $word[0]);
    }
    return implode( '', $acronym);
}
```

Note that both functions will fail for inputs like `Hello    World`. I am leaving it up to the OP to make these modifications (if necessary).

Comment: Hey @nickb, just a quick question. Suppose I would like to get the last word of the array and probably array_push it on the array how do it do it? For example, if am to input Automated Teller Machine, then the output would be like ATM Machine. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: One more (stylistic) error: don't call your function Acronym with upper-case A. When someone else reads your code they'll think it's a class, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

you are running your loop on `$count` which is getting its value from `str_len` its an array because of return on `$text = str_split($text);`

So you have overwritten your `$text` variable you can fix it by changing order get length first then split.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your first variable `$text`

```
$count = strlen($text);
```

In this line `$text` is an array, because you changed it in the first line of your method.

Try inverting the two first lines:

```
$count = strlen($text);
$text = str_split($text);
```

**Note**

This will solve your secondary problem, and enable your algorithm to run without errors. It doesn't fix your algorithm, but at least you will be able to debug it now.

Answer (score 0):

`str_split` turns the string into an array.

`str_length` brings the length of a string which you have overwritten with an array already. you need `count()`